# SSRS/Power BI Report Builder - show textbox for first page of a group and hide otherwise

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to show the text in the green box for every first page of a new **Operation** and hide it for any pages that aren't the first page of a new **Operation**.

[Picture of my Tablix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wBis.png)

A little background of the dataset - any given **Material** can have multiple **Operations** and any **Operation** can have multiple **Characteristics**. My issue is that an **Operation** can span multiple pages if it has multiple **Characteristics** but the the text in Green will keep repeating for each new page. I only need it to be shown on the first page for any new **Operation**. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

(I'm writing this from memory so it might not be 100% accurate)

Assuming you have a row group that groups by operation, then you can insert an extra row into that row group. To do this, right click your exising row and do 'insert row, inside group, above/before'

Now you have two rows, in the top row, merge the cells horizontally, then insert a tablix into the newly merged cell. In that tablix, add the 'header' details. You probably need to use `=FIRST()` in your expression here assuming the details you need are repeated on each row in your dataset.

It looks like you already have a tablix in the second row so that can stay as it is.

If this doesn't help, show your current report design including all rows groups and there properties such as what the are grouped on...

Comment: Thank you! This worked almost perfectly. My only issue is that on pages where the header is not included, I have a little extra "tail" trailing the bottom of the tablix when I print to PDF. Do you know how I would remove it? You can see what I mean here: https://imgur.com/Zplab2j

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the overall report design. If you mean the tall column to the left, that *might* be caused by having whitespace under the tablix. You could also try setting the `ConsumeCOntainerWhietspace` report property to `True'. If this doesn't help, start a new question and reference this one, include your report design in design mode.